# Best solution for patterning 3d models in c# application

Tags: c#, opengl, 3d

I have good knowledge in c# and i worked with OpenGL, but not a 3d expert, so please provide me your offers and your best practices for my following problem:

My desired windows application should load a 3d model (for example a 3d model of a room) and pattern specified section of the room with the user's selected material patterns (a specific wall and a specific part of the roof for example). As models my vary from project to project i thought it might be the best to create models in 3dMax or such 3d modeling software and load it dynamically in the application, but i don't know if it's even possible, and if it is , how do i specify the section which i desire to pattern them in c# application, and how to pattern them.

Please provide me some topics to search, a best practice, any thing that would help me figure out is appreciable.

Regards

Comment: What is a "3 model" Do you mean "3D model"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In overall what you've described is correct approach and just need to be specified a bit here & there. There are couple of questions you have to answer before:

1. Do you need to create models on your own? Or is it ok to download freely available models from the internet? This question is actually: "do you need something so special that it is impossible to find a free model"? One of the sites which offers free 3d models is: http://thefree3dmodels.com/
2. If you need to create models - do you have a licence for 3dStudio? Are you allowed to use it a student? If not - [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) may be your app of choice. Please mind, that it will take some time for you to get familiar with the app.
3. What library do you want to use? You've mentioned that you're familiar with OpenGL. I believe the best approach to use OpenGL with C#/.NET apps is to use [OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com). You may also consider using [XNA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/centrum-xna.aspx) or a very thin. managed wrapper on DirectX - [SlimDX](http://slimdx.org)

Displaying the models on the screen should be pretty easy. You'll easily find a lot of tutorials on the Internet showing how to achieve that. Having this done, the only thing that you need to think of is to change the properties of the model, so new texture (pattern) is going to be applied to the model. You may also change some other properties like colors and properties of the material (as some libraries call it).

Comment: Dear @MaciekTalaska and thanks for your time. 1,2) Yes these models are really specific and models will be created by the owner of the app and sure he has the 3dStudio license.  3) i prefer OpenTK also. But would you please also say me that what is kind (ext) of the file i should output from 3ds and load it in c# app and how to specify the pattern-able sections?

Comment: If you're asking for the type of 3d model format it would be the best to use - the answer is tricky. 3ds is still kind of a standard. It should be easy to find a library for C# that will load a 3ds model from file. For XNA & DirectX it may be convenient to use Microsoft's own .X format. It could be actually driven by owner of the app I assume. For models only I think I would recommend sticking to .3ds as it is popular. If you want to create model loading library on your own there are other easier formats to choose from (Wavefront's .obj being one of them).